# Sort a dictionary by list of lists

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a dictionary by list of lists. The items in the list of lists are keys in the dictionary.  I asked it before but the answers didn't solve the issue.

My input list is:

```
   mylist= [
    ['why', 'was', 'cinderella', 'late', 'for', 'the', 'ball', 'she', 'forgot', 'to', 'swing', 'the', 'bat'],
    ['why', 'is', 'the', 'little', 'duck', 'always', 'so', 'sad', 'because', 'he', 'always', 'sees', 'a', 'bill', 'in', 'front', 'of', 'his', 'face'],
    ['what', 'has', 'four', 'legs', 'and', 'goes', 'booo', 'a', 'cow', 'with', 'a', 'cold'], 
    ['what', 'is', 'a', 'caterpillar', 'afraid', 'of', 'a', 'dogerpillar'],
    ['what', 'did', 'the', 'crop', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'farmer', 'why', 'are', 'you', 'always', 'picking', 'on', 'me']
    ]
```

My dictionary somewhat looks like this:

```
    myDict = {'to': [7, 11, 17, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 37, 39, 41, 47, 48, 53, 56], 
    'jam': [20], 'black': [5], 'farmer': [11],
    'woodchuck': [54], 'has': [14, 16, 51], 'who': [16]
    }
```

My code is:

```
    def sort_by_increasing_order(mylist, myDict):
    #temp = sorted(myDict, key=myDict.get)
    temp = sorted(myDict, key=lambda tempKey: for tempKey in mylist, reverse=True )
    return temp
```

Something like:

```
    sort_by_increasing_order(['d', 'e', 'f'], {'d': [0, 1], 'e': [1, 2, 3], 'f': [4]})
    result: ['f', 'e', 'd']
```

So for my sample input it would look like:

```
        sort_by_increasing_order(mylist, myDict)
        >> ['to','woodchuck','has','jam','who','farmer']
```

The commented line just sorts by the dictionary keys when i try to sort by the list. My approach is not correct. The result should a list with increasing order of the length of indices as mentioned above. Any suggestion.

Comment: How would you be comparing the keys?

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary by keys. Dictionary is by definition not sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to `@doukremt` answer 
assuming you are aware of decorators.

```
mydict = {'d': [0, 1], 'e': [1, 2, 3], 'f': [4]}
mylist = [['d', 'e', 'f', 'c'], ['c', 'v', 'd', 'n']]

def convert_to_set(mylist, result_set=None):
    if result_set is None:
        result_set = []
    for item in mylist:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            result_set.append(item)
        if isinstance(item, list):
            convert_to_set(item, result_set)
    return set(result_set)

def list_to_set(f):
    def wrapper(mylist, mydict):
        myset = convert_to_set(mylist)
        result = f(myset, mydict)
        return result
    return wrapper

@list_to_set
def findit(mylist, mydict):
    gen = ((k, mydict[k]) for k in mylist if k in mydict)
    return [k for k, v in sorted(gen, key=lambda p: len(p[1]))]

print findit(mylist, mydict)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Let me try it out. I am sorry i am not aware of decorators. If you could explain what your code is doing that would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python/1594484#1594484  here

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out.

Comment: can you please explain the flow etc, it would be helpful. I am not able to understand it. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I have converted nested list to set. so that all keywords in list and sublist will be inside set (without duplicate). Decorator is to just convert your nested list parameter (mylist) to set. Now, findit will operate on set instaed of original mylist. in short  [['d', 'e', 'f', 'c'], ['c', 'v', 'd', 'n']] => {'d', 'e', 'c', 'v', 'f', 'n'}

Comment: :) Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> D= {'to': [7, 11, 17, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 37, 39, 41, 47, 48, 53, 56], 
...     'jam': [20], 'black': [5], 'farmer': [11],
...     'woodchuck': [54], 'has': [14, 16, 51], 'who': [16]
...     }
>>> 
>>> sorted(D, key=lambda k:len(D[k]), reverse=True)
['to', 'has', 'who', 'jam', 'black', 'farmer', 'woodchuck']
```

For the values

```
>>> sorted(D.values(), key=len, reverse=True)
[[7, 11, 17, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 37, 39, 41, 47, 48, 53, 56], [14, 16, 51], [16], [20], [5], [11], [54]]
```

For (keys, values)

```
>>> sorted(D.items(), key=lambda i:len(i[1]), reverse=True)
[('to', [7, 11, 17, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 37, 39, 41, 47, 48, 53, 56]), ('has', [14, 16, 51]), ('who', [16]), ('jam', [20]), ('black', [5]), ('farmer', [11]), ('woodchuck', [54])]
```

**Edit:** Still not really clear what you are asking for. Your example doesn't seem to care about the length at all, otherwise "has" should come before "woodchuck"? Changing `len` to `max` may be what you want

```
>>> D = {'to': [7, 11, 17, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 37, 39, 41, 47, 48, 53, 56], 
...     'jam': [20], 'black': [5], 'farmer': [11],
...     'woodchuck': [54], 'has': [14, 16, 51], 'who': [16]
...     }
>>> 
>>> sorted(D, key=lambda k:max(D[k]), reverse=True)
['to', 'woodchuck', 'has', 'jam', 'who', 'farmer', 'black']
>>> sorted(D.values(), key=max, reverse=True)
[[7, 11, 17, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 37, 39, 41, 47, 48, 53, 56], [54], [14, 16, 51], [20], [16], [11], [5]]
>>> sorted(D.items(), key=lambda i:max(i[1]), reverse=True)
[('to', [7, 11, 17, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 37, 39, 41, 47, 48, 53, 56]), ('woodchuck', [54]), ('has', [14, 16, 51]), ('jam', [20]), ('who', [16]), ('farmer', [11]), ('black', [5])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This returns the keys. What if i want to return the values?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it's not sorting with respect of the list of lists?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking (perhaps noone here does). Can you clarify your question with a proper example?

Comment: i have updated it. Please let me know if this is clear to you now.

Comment: @user3247054, I've updated my answer. I don't see how the length comes into it though

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out. Please see other answer which considers the list of lists for dictionary sorting.

Answer (score 1):

```
def findit(mylist, mydict):
    gen = ((k, mydict[k]) for k in mylist if k in mydict)
    return [k for k, v in sorted(gen, key=lambda p: len(p[1]))]


>>> findit(['d', 'e', 'f'], {'d': [0, 1], 'e': [1, 2, 3], 'f': [4]})
['f', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. If yours is doing on single list, while i have list of lists posted above.

Comment: @user3247054: Then you must either convert your nested lists to tuples, or use a different data structure. You can't search for lists in dictionaries

Comment: If I understood correctly, You have list of list keywords, keyword can be present in any sub list. So, I would suggest convert list of list to single set so that it will contains all keywords as strings and use above code. List are not hashable so can not be used as dict keys.

Comment: @doukremt if want to return the indices. what would be change in the code?

Comment: Never mind figured it out.